# filereader, checking checksum for image with SparkMD5, promises

Tags: javascript, md5, filereader

Im trying to count checksum with SparkMD5 library, I properly read ArrayBuffer from file, with FileReader, and I`m passing ArrayBuffer to my new function:

```
countMD5Hash = function(data){
    return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
        let res = null;

        res = SparkMD5.ArrayBuffer.hash(data)

        if(res){
             resolve(res)
        }
    });
};
```

When I`m trying to invoke countMD5Hash like above, it returns undefined, but when Im trying to console.log in this function without resolving, it logs the proper checksum. How to do that function will resolve response with counted checksum?

Answer (score 1):

Resolving a promise is not about returning a value. To use the resovled value, you should use `then` like this:

```
countMD5Hash(data).then(result => {
    // do whatever you want with the result
})
```

However, if you are using `countMD5Hash` in an `async` function, you can also use `await` like this:

```
let handle = async function(data) {
    // this waits for the promise to fulfill (or reject! don't forget to deal with exceptions!)
    // and puts the resolved value into hash
    let hash = await countMD5Hash(data); 
    // do whatever you want with hash
}
```

Comment: @ArturJuźwik if this solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick sign